# Bake the codebase into production images

Tags: git, docker, production-environment

I'm currently using **git** to deploy my applications in my different hosts. My codebase being mounted into running **Docker images**:

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
services:
    app:
        image: my.registry.net:5000/my/app
        volumes:
            - .:/app
# [...]
```

So my deployments are like that:

```
$ git pull
$ docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose exec app some_dependencies_installation_command
$ docker-compose exec app some_cache_clearing_command
```

That seems **wrong** to me for many reasons that you can imagine. Though if something is going wrong I still can **revert** to my previous git release tag.

I'd like to simplify my deployments by baking my codebase into the image, so I **don't use git anymore** for deployments but rather rely on **image pull**. Don't hesitate to tell me if you don't suggest that and why.

I'm tempted to simply add my codebase to the end of my image and mounting just the required stuff in the host:

**Dockerfile**

```sh
# [...]
ADD . /app
```

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

```yaml
services:
    app:
        image: my.registry.net:5000/my/app
        volumes:
            - ./config.yml:/app/config.yml
            - ./logs:/app/logs
            - ./cache:/app/cache
            - ./sessions:/app/sessions
# [...]
```

So once built, I should only have to deploy my images with:

```
$ docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d
```

Would it be the good way to go ? How can I version my image so I can **revert** it if something goes wrong (since the `Dockerfile` actually **never changes**) ? Also, isn't relying on one layer of the Dockerfile going to **pull the entire codebase** each time instead of only the diff (like with git) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding source code onto the container, is usually done to have a quick feedback loop while developing. This is achieved by avoiding rebuilding the image once code changes as done. This technique is mostly useful for local development  purposes. For production environments this technique should not be used.

Docker images are designed to be self-contained. All the dependencies that an image needs should be packaged inside the image. Relying on bind mounts to provide the source code or dependencies is not 
recommended as the resulting Docker image is not portable. Whenever you switch to a new machine, you need to transfer that source code and dependencies to that new machine.

Thus adding the source code into the image is the recommended approach. You should also benefit from the standard Docker workflow, where you build the image giving it a specific tag (usually the version), and push
it into a Docker repository. From there on, you only pull the image and start it on any machine that you have.

As for the versioning: When building the image you tag it with the source code version(or git tag or commit id).

```
docker build -t <image-name>:<version> .
```

And you also pull a specific version using `docker pull <image-name>:<version>`. Using this technique, you can always revert back to any version of the image.

Comment: Image portability is indeed an issue

Answer (score 1):

docker-compose is one orchestration tool for docker, but there others like kubernetes or docker swarm. You should check them out for yourself, considering where you can use these tools.

To version your images you can tag them (with -t ). So you will be able to roll out specific version `my.registry.net:5000/my/app:1.1.0`, etc.

The build can be done locally on your machine or automated in a CI/CD pipeline.

Docker does not pull the codebase, only layers with files. If you compile your program, only the the binary should be added and some assets. Layers are cached and only pulled on when needed.

If you want to minimize the images in your registry, you can use multi stage builds in docker. This uses multiple stages to build the last container, which only serves your app, and therefore needs less files. E.g. you can compile your binary in one stage with javac, compile the assets in another stage with nodejs and webpack and copy those resulting files to the last container which only has the java runtime and the static, generated assets. The official docs are here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: I'll take a look at Docker swarm, I'm always thinking it is only for scaling considerations but it seems like doing more

Comment: About the layer, for non compiled source with their dependencies it can be quite a big one... but I'm not sure how I could do else

Comment: In that case you have to add them. There is no way around that. You should consider adding them last, because those will files will change the most.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, your approach has a number of issues, including:

- [Your containers are not ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#general-guidelines-and-recommendations)
- Each instance of your application has to wait for the build to complete before starting
- What happens if your build fails? Excluding manual testing, you only know for failures at "deploy time"
- The build process will produce the same artifact on each run (provided you did not change the source). Why waste time repeating this process?

Instead of baking the source code of your app inside the container and rebuilding your app on each deploy, you could just build your app (maybe inside another "build" container if you want to make the build environment portable too, i.e. a container used just for building) and add the artifacts that your build produced in another image that will be deployed in your production environment (after testing and QA, because you do have multiple environments, right? :).

Docker image tagging could work this way: build an image on each commit (maybe under the latest image tag) and on each git tag (under the corresponding image tag). Example: for each commit on your master branch you "update" `your-image:latest` and when you tag the 1.0.0 version you produce the `your-image:1.0.0`.

If you have a CI service of sorts you may also automate this procedure.

Note that using the latest tag in production may lead to unstable environments because you don't know which version you are deploying. Use another more-specific tag.

UPDATE: as others have been pointing out, putting your sources inside the container is a strategy that you can apply to the development phase. But it's not your case, because I am assuming you are talking about (pre-)production deplyoments.

Comment: Ok I should indeed have a dedicated build step before each deployment. About the source, well for non compiled apps like javascript or php, we have to include them all into the image anyway.

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY It's not necessarily true because even with JS, HTML and CSS you may have some gulp/grunt tasks to minimize, compress, sourcemap etc. your files